# Datalabs project not found

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

I am trying to run Datalabs with the instructions documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-gce), whenever I try to start docker, it tells me my project cannot be found. I already set my project using

```
gcloud set project my-project
```

I looked at the [datalabs/run.sh](https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/blob/master/containers/datalab/content/run.sh) code from datalabs and it seems to get my projects with my e-mail using `gcloud auth list --format="value(account)"`, if I run this in my terminal, I get a list of 3 emails, (I use various service accounts). Could this be the problem? This was working a month ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the multiple accounts is probably part of the issue.

More specifically, from what you describe, the most likely issue is a mismatch between your active account and your set project.

If you have multiple accounts signed in to gcloud, then one of them will be set as the "active" account. The credentials for that account are what will be used for every gcloud command. If that account is not a member of the project you've  chosen, then you will get this error message.

You can see which account is active by running `gcloud auth list`, and looking for the one with the word 'ACTIVE' next to it.

To change which account is active, run `gcloud config set account ...`.

As for the code you found, that is not actually used when getting the project. The email address returned from that call is only used for two (unrelated) things:

1. To check if there are *any* authenticated accounts available.
2. To figure out a reasonable account name to use when SSH'ing into the VM.